# Difference between "Batman: Arkham Asylum" on PS3 and XBox 360

Tags: version-differences, batman-arkham-asylum

What differences are there between "Batman: Arkham Asylum" on PS3 and XBox 360?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here](http://www.playfire.com/a/forum/batman-arkham-asylum/thread/47725)'s a comparison

> #### GRAPHICS
>
> Although both consoles had issues, the PlayStation 3 had a few less and having a camera that shows more helps when being attacked from all angles, or if you need to find a place to hide.
>
> #### PERFORMANCE
>
> Both consoles dropped frames and there was screen tearing. It would have been nice to see one console with neither screen tearing nor frame skipping.
>
> #### CONTROL
>
> Tie. Identical controls.
>
> #### LOADING
>
> Tie. The PlayStation 3 has a 1 gig install that took only 3 minutes and yet one could argue that with a mandatory install, PlayStation 3 should have performed better. However the latter could counter that if the Xbox 360 had a mandatory install it should have done better…which we know is impossible since not everyone has a hard drive.
>
> #### OUTCOME
>
> Although we’re pretty sure you’re gonna be happy with buying Batman: Arkham Asylum on either console, we believe the PlayStation 3 is the better game even if it wasn’t a perfect win.

And [here](http://ps3.ign.com/articles/102/1021087p1.html)'s a little more serious one

Answer (score 9):

On PS3 you can play as Joker in the challenge levels.

Comment: That's a surprise!

Answer (score 1):

In terms of gameplay? None whatsoever. The visuals are a bit different on each system, as seen in this [article](http://www.eurogamer.pt/gallery.php?game_id=10313&article_id=689496).